# Upgrading drush under Windows using self-update

Tags: drush, upgrading

I installed Drush on a W/XP workstation using MSI and want to upgrade it.
I've tried using `drush self-update` but the suggestions it gives all seem to pertain more to Unix installations than Windows.
The best suggestion looks like drush dl /path/to/drush but I'm not 100% sure what the /path/to/drush would be on a W/XP system.

Answer (score 1):

If you stick to using the *Pear* installation method for Drush then you can just update all Pear modules (or just Drush) at will. I don't even see the `selfupdate` command in Drush 6.2, but it just may be hidden now.

Answer (score 0):

> In WinXP the folder to copy into is C:\Documents and Settings\All
> Users\Application Data\Drush. The Application Data directory is also a
> hidden folder. (Please see above instructions regarding hidden
> folders).
>
> There is an extra folder named classes (containing one file named
> DrushRole.php) in the unzipped drush-All-versions-5.x-dev that was not
> in the download on the Windows 7 machine. I went ahead and copied it
> over with all the others into the C:\Documents and Settings\All
> Users\Application Data\Drush directory with all the rest of the
> folders and files.
>
> Source : https://groups.drupal.org/node/265678

You can read more about upgrading drush on Windows XP, by this [article](https://groups.drupal.org/node/265678)